# Talend: REST Call results in either "URI is not absolute" or "UnknownHostException"

Tags: rest, uri, etl, talend

I am trying to get data from a REST API to our database with the help of Talend Jaspersoft ETL Express Version 5.6.
To make sure that my problem is not related to our server configuration i installed the tool locally too and got stuck. Since I am a student who is not well experienced with java but needs to get this run for his company i hope you can help me. I have only some basic knowledge so i did not try to find a solution in the "Code" tab, only worked with the Designer.

In the end I wanted to try out the following tutorial:
http://dwetl.com/2015/08/11/trest-use-case-example-use-rest-api-in-talend/
but that don't works too for me. I can get the data when i use the call in my browser but with that tool i am getting only errors.

With "https://api.github.com/users/mralexgray/followers" as URL I get an UnknownHostException:

```
    Starte Job Test am 11:20 21/07/2016.

[statistics] connecting to socket on port 3941
[statistics] connected
Exception in component tREST_1
com.sun.jersey.api.client.ClientHandlerException: java.net.UnknownHostException: api.github.com
    at com.sun.jersey.client.urlconnection.URLConnectionClientHandler.handle(URLConnectionClientHandler.java:131)
    at com.sun.jersey.api.client.Client.handle(Client.java:616)
    at com.sun.jersey.api.client.WebResource.handle(WebResource.java:559)
    at com.sun.jersey.api.client.WebResource.get(WebResource.java:182)
    at testetl.test_0_1.Test.tREST_1Process(Test.java:572)
    at testetl.test_0_1.Test.runJobInTOS(Test.java:929)
    at testetl.test_0_1.Test.main(Test.java:786)
Caused by: java.net.UnknownHostException: api.github.com
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.BaseSSLSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.NetworkClient.doConnect(Unknown Source)
[statistics] disconnected
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.New(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.getNewHttpClient(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.HttpURLConnection.getResponseCode(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getResponseCode(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.jersey.client.urlconnection.URLConnectionClientHandler._invoke(URLConnectionClientHandler.java:218)
    at com.sun.jersey.client.urlconnection.URLConnectionClientHandler.handle(URLConnectionClientHandler.java:129)
    ... 6 more
Job Test endet am 11:20 21/07/2016. [exit code=1]
```

If I cut off that "https://" part and use "api.github.com/users/mralexgray/followers" as Url I get the error "Uri is not absolute"

```
Starte Job Test am 11:31 21/07/2016.

[statistics] connecting to socket on port 3809
[statistics] connected
Exception in component tREST_1
com.sun.jersey.api.client.ClientHandlerException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: URI is not absolute
    at com.sun.jersey.client.urlconnection.URLConnectionClientHandler.handle(URLConnectionClientHandler.java:131)
    at com.sun.jersey.api.client.Client.handle(Client.java:616)
    at com.sun.jersey.api.client.WebResource.handle(WebResource.java:559)
    at com.sun.jersey.api.client.WebResource.get(WebResource.java:182)
    at testetl.test_0_1.Test.tREST_1Process(Test.java:572)
    at testetl.test_0_1.Test.runJobInTOS(Test.java:929)
    at testetl.test_0_1.Test.main(Test.java:786)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: URI is not absolute
    at java.net.URI.toURL(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.jersey.client.urlconnection.URLConnectionClientHandler._invoke(URLConnectionClientHandler.java:140)
    at com.sun.jersey.client.urlconnection.URLConnectionClientHandler.handle(URLConnectionClientHandler.java:129)
    ... 6 more
[statistics] disconnected
Job Test endet am 11:31 21/07/2016. [exit code=1]
```

Just to give you as many information as possible, here is a little part out of the auto generated java code which seems to be about this REST Call for me, but maybe I am completly wrong and this dont helps at all since I have only basic java knowledge:

```
        /**
         * [tREST_1 begin ] start
         */

        ok_Hash.put("tREST_1", false);
        start_Hash.put("tREST_1", System.currentTimeMillis());

        currentComponent = "tREST_1";

        int tos_count_tREST_1 = 0;

        String endpoint_tREST_1 = "api.github.com/users/mralexgray/followers";

        String trustStoreFile_tREST_1 = System
                .getProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStore");
        String trustStoreType_tREST_1 = System
                .getProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStoreType");
        String trustStorePWD_tREST_1 = System
                .getProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword");

        String keyStoreFile_tREST_1 = System
                .getProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStore");
        String keyStoreType_tREST_1 = System
                .getProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStoreType");
        String keyStorePWD_tREST_1 = System
                .getProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword");

        com.sun.jersey.api.client.config.ClientConfig config_tREST_1 = new com.sun.jersey.api.client.config.DefaultClientConfig();
        javax.net.ssl.SSLContext ctx_tREST_1 = javax.net.ssl.SSLContext
                .getInstance("SSL");

        javax.net.ssl.TrustManager[] tms_tREST_1 = null;
        if (trustStoreFile_tREST_1 != null
                && trustStoreType_tREST_1 != null) {
            char[] password_tREST_1 = null;
            if (trustStorePWD_tREST_1 != null)
                password_tREST_1 = trustStorePWD_tREST_1.toCharArray();
            java.security.KeyStore trustStore_tREST_1 = java.security.KeyStore
                    .getInstance(trustStoreType_tREST_1);
            trustStore_tREST_1.load(new java.io.FileInputStream(
                    trustStoreFile_tREST_1), password_tREST_1);

            javax.net.ssl.TrustManagerFactory tmf_tREST_1 = javax.net.ssl.TrustManagerFactory
                    .getInstance(javax.net.ssl.KeyManagerFactory
                            .getDefaultAlgorithm());
            tmf_tREST_1.init(trustStore_tREST_1);
            tms_tREST_1 = tmf_tREST_1.getTrustManagers();
        }

        javax.net.ssl.KeyManager[] kms_tREST_1 = null;
        if (keyStoreFile_tREST_1 != null
                && keyStoreType_tREST_1 != null) {
            char[] password_tREST_1 = null;
            if (keyStorePWD_tREST_1 != null)
                password_tREST_1 = keyStorePWD_tREST_1.toCharArray();
            java.security.KeyStore keyStore_tREST_1 = java.security.KeyStore
                    .getInstance(keyStoreType_tREST_1);
            keyStore_tREST_1.load(new java.io.FileInputStream(
                    keyStoreFile_tREST_1), password_tREST_1);

            javax.net.ssl.KeyManagerFactory kmf_tREST_1 = javax.net.ssl.KeyManagerFactory
                    .getInstance(javax.net.ssl.KeyManagerFactory
                            .getDefaultAlgorithm());
            kmf_tREST_1.init(keyStore_tREST_1, password_tREST_1);
            kms_tREST_1 = kmf_tREST_1.getKeyManagers();
        }

        ctx_tREST_1.init(kms_tREST_1, tms_tREST_1, null);
        config_tREST_1
                .getProperties()
                .put(com.sun.jersey.client.urlconnection.HTTPSProperties.PROPERTY_HTTPS_PROPERTIES,
                        new com.sun.jersey.client.urlconnection.HTTPSProperties(
                                new javax.net.ssl.HostnameVerifier() {

                                    public boolean verify(
                                            String hostName,
                                            javax.net.ssl.SSLSession session) {
                                        return true;
                                    }
                                }, ctx_tREST_1));

        com.sun.jersey.api.client.Client restClient_tREST_1 = com.sun.jersey.api.client.Client
                .create(config_tREST_1);
        com.sun.jersey.api.client.WebResource restResource_tREST_1;
        if (endpoint_tREST_1 != null && !("").equals(endpoint_tREST_1)) {
            restResource_tREST_1 = restClient_tREST_1
                    .resource(endpoint_tREST_1);
        } else {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("url can't be empty!");
        }

        com.sun.jersey.api.client.ClientResponse errorResponse_tREST_1 = null;
        String restResponse_tREST_1 = "";
        try {

            restResponse_tREST_1 = restResource_tREST_1

            .get(String.class);

        } catch (com.sun.jersey.api.client.UniformInterfaceException ue) {
            errorResponse_tREST_1 = ue.getResponse();
        }

        // for output

        row1 = new row1Struct();
        if (errorResponse_tREST_1 != null) {
            row1.ERROR_CODE = errorResponse_tREST_1.getStatus();
        } else {
            row1.Body = restResponse_tREST_1;
        }

        /**
         * [tREST_1 begin ] stop
         */

        /**
         * [tREST_1 main ] start
         */
```

Any help would be very appreciated :). All my examples are about that tutorial but while I was trying to get our real API to work with ETL I just got the exact same problems and I guess this tutorial is easier to give you guys as an example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

java.net.UnknownHostException : Did you check if you are behind a proxy ? The previous error should happen if, from your studio position, the site is not accessible.

You have to know that your browser doesn't necessarily have the same configuration as Talend Studio. So, please check your "Internet Settings" for the existing of any proxy. If it is the case, then it is possible to change the proxy settings in menu:  Window -> Preferences, under General -> Network.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I am in the company again today and so i checked asap that proxy thing. If I go to C:\WINDOWS\System32\inetcpl.cpl and look in the Connections Tab it shows me nothing is set up. For the LAN Settings is a Proxy Server set, now i tried to uncheck the "Bypass proxy server for local addresses", if I do so i am getting a different error, i uploaded it to pastebin: http://pastebin.com/USZ4yraz

So for me it seems, that the set up proxy seems to be alright and i need to leave this box checked? Maybe i could try something else with those proxy settings?

Comment: I just realized, that the error is not different because i unchecked that checkbox. The error messages i postet when i created this thread had been from using my local installation. Checking my local proxy settings showed me, that there is a fixed "automatic configuration" i can not change because my company don't give me the rights to do so.
On the server which should be used in the end this is not the case but we use a proxy server manually. Still it seems to dont affect the servers message (see pastebin) at all when I turn this proxy on or off

Comment: As I write in my previous message, if there IS a proxy set in Internet Settings, you have to set it as well for Talend Studio. Talend Studio doesn't take automatically the system settings for proxy.

Comment: You have to go to Talend Studio -> Window -> Preferences, under General -> Network Connections. You will find the proxy settings. There you have to switch the Active Provider to "Native" (or put the manual proxy settings).

Comment: Ah sorry, I did not got, that this was about the Talend Studio itself.
But in those settings it was at Native and the proxy was also written in it, i tried to change it to manual and write the proxy there too but that dont helps - the error remains

Answer (score 1):

We finally could figure out a way to solve our connection issue.
I don't know why Talend is not using our proxy correctly even if its manually set up in the preferences but if we use the tSetProxy component it works and gets the expected JSON object back from the server.